# How to render a multiple partials in one view using ajax in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been struggling with an error appearing while rendering multiple partials to one specific page. A have 4 different buttons in my administration panel and I want each of them to call an ajax call to render 4 different partials accordingly. Unfortunately, when I'm trying to make it happen, it happens to work on one button only, the rest doesn't respond at all.

Here's my action in controller:

```
  def administration
    @orders = Order.all 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json 
      format.html 
      format.js
      end
  end
```

My view:

```
    <% provide(:title, "Administration") %>
     <h1>Manage your site</h1>

<section>
    <div class="tabs tabs-style-bar">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><%= link_to "Masters", {:controller => 'masters', :action => 'index'}, class: "link fa fa-group", :remote => true %>
                </li>
                <li><%= link_to "Orders", {:controller => 'masters', :action => 'administration'}, class: "fa fa-tasks", :remote => true %>
                </li>
                <li><%= link_to "Services", {:controller => 'masters',  :action => 'services'}, class: "fa fa-tags", :remote => true %>
                </li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_master_path(current_master), class: "fa fa-cogs" %>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div><!-- /tabs -->
</section>

<div class="orders"></div>
<div class="masters"></div>
<div class="services"></div>
```

and My JS receiver:

```
var orders_inject = $("<%= j raw render 'orders' %>");
 $('.orders').html(orders_inject);
```

So please, let me work it all out as it's been quite long since the error occurred!

Comment: What is the error? Please post it in the question.

Comment: The problem is that in my view I receive both partials at the same time hence I don't know how to make them appear on independent separate calls.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you, try this and change your render files. I just suppose here partial `test1` and `test2`

```
$(".orders").replaceWith("<%= j(render('test1') %>");

$(".services").replaceWith("<%= j(render('test2') %>");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It changes nothing((

Comment: let me think about it.